# Is it possible the condition in IF ELSE statement is a method?

Tags: java, android

i was wondering if its possible for  method to be the condition in if else statements.

i have a method called takephoto(). if takephoto() was successfully done it will do another method.

i did it this way

```
if (takephoto() == true)

 {
     anothermethod();
 }
```

i get an error that says

The operator == is undefined for the argument type(s) void, boolean

for the line

```
if (takephoto() == true)
```

this is my takephoto()method

```
public static void takePhoto() {
    if(camera != null) {
        camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureTakenHandler);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to make your `takephoto()` return a `boolean`, not a `void` value.

**---- EDIT ----**

```
public static boolean takePhoto() {
    if(camera != null) {
        camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureTakenHandler);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: how do i do the statement if it does return a void value? thanks

Comment: If it returns a void value, you can't do that comparison. Void is the empty value, so you can't compare "empty" to anything. You'll have to return boolean in your function, in this case.

Comment: public static void takePhoto() {
    if(camera != null) {
        camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureTakenHandler);
    }
}

in this method i try putting a return true, but it seems its only for boolean. how do i place return if its not returning a boolean?

Answer (score 4):

The method `takephoto` should return `boolean`, not `void` (i.e. nothing).

Then the answer is yes, but you should write it like this:

```
if (takephoto()) {
    // do something
}
```

Your version will work too but this one is simpler and cleaner.

Comment: my takephoto() method is an action that does not return a boolean.  by the way. if i do this i would still get anerror. saying cannot convert void to boolean. thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean by action but OK. If your method returns void, then you cannot use it in an if statement as a condition.

Answer (score 2):

If `takephoto()` returns a boolean, that return value is itself the condition for your `if` statement, so you can write it as:

```
if (takephoto()) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this but your takephoto() method should return either true or false.

```
public static boolean takephoto(){
    //if the code was successful
    return true;
}
```

Or return false if picture was unsuccessful.

**Here's how you could fix it:**

```
public static boolean takePhoto() {
if(camera != null) {
    camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureTakenHandler);
    return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: i forgot to mention that my takephoto method is not a boolean type. what should i do in order for me to make it a condition?

Comment: It needs to be a boolean type or else you won't be able to do it. Why don't you make it a boolean type? The method will be exactly the same as now except that it will additionally return true or false, which solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (takephoto()) {

}

public boolean takephoto()
{
    return true; //or false
}
```

Comment: what if takephoto does not return a boolean. takephoto() does an action by the way. public static void takePhoto() {
    if(camera != null) {
        camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureTakenHandler);
    }
}
thanks

Comment: It must return a boolean or it will not compile. If it's not returning a boolean then whats the point of having it as a if statement right? It could just be evaulated before or after

Answer (score 0):

You say "if takephoto() was successfully done it will do another method." You have to have a way for takephoto to indicate if it was successful. The way you do that is to return a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can, but if statement checks between two parameters of same type.

your if statement:

```
if (takephoto())
{
    ///if takephoto() true
    anothermethod();
}
```

your takephoto method:

```
public static boolean takePhoto() {
    if(camera != null) {
        camera.takePicture(null, null, pictureTakenHandler);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```